# Replacing items in a dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops

I am new to python and programming and need some help replacing items in a dictionary of lists. I would like to replace `None` with `'None'` in the dictionary below:

```
dict = {'Chester100': ['Caesar, Augustus', '05/10/2012', '09/09/2012', None],
        'Rochester102': ['Henrich, Norton', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', None],
        'Rochester100': ['Caeser, Julius', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', None],
        'Rochester101': [None, None, None, '08/18/2012']}
```

My code is as follows:

```
new_dict = {}

for i in dict: #This accesses each dictionary key.
    temp = []
    for j in dict[i]: #This iterates through the inner lists
        if j is None:
            temp.append('None')
        else:
            temp.append(j)
        temp2 = {str(i):temp}
        new_dict.update(temp2)

    print(new_dict)
```

yields

```
{'Chester100': ['Caesar, Augustus', '05/10/2012', '09/09/2012', 'None'], 
'Rochester102': ['Henrich, Norton', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', 'None'], 
'Rochester100': ['Caeser, Julius', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', 'None'], 
'Rochester101': ['None', 'None', 'None', '08/18/2012']}
```

Is there a way to do this in a fewer lines of code or more efficiently using list comprehension or other methods? Should nested for loop (as I have it in my code) be avoided? Thanks.

**Using Python 3.4.1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k:[e if e is not None else 'None' for e in v] for k,v in di.items()}
{'Rochester102': ['Henrich, Norton', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', 'None'], 'Rochester100': ['Caeser, Julius', '08/18/2014', '12/17/2014', 'None'], 'Rochester101': ['None', 'None', 'None', '08/18/2012'], 'Chester100': ['Caesar, Augustus', '05/10/2012', '09/09/2012', 'None']}
```

And don't name a dict `dict` since it will mask the built in function by that name.

---

If you have *huge* dicts or lists, you may want to modify your data in place. If so, this may be the most efficient:

```
for key, value in di.items():
    for i, e in enumerate(value):
        if e is None: di[key][i]='None'
```

Comment: You should use `v` instead of `di[k]`.

Comment: Why use `di[k]` when you have `v`?

Comment: My bad `:-0` -- fixed. I originally had `{k:[e if e is not None else 'None' for e in di[k]] for k in di}` until I saw Python 3 and change one without changing the other...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this in a fewer lines of code or more efficiently
>   using list comprehension or other methods?

Yes, provided you know how to implement dictionary comprehension and list comprehension. 
**Note**, question similar to this has been asked numerous times, where user knows a way to code via loops but fails to comprehend how to achieve this in a comprehensive way.

Considering this, I will take your example code and translate in as a dict + list comprehension fashion

**Your Code**

```
new_dict = {}

for i in dict: #This accesses each dictionary key.
    temp = []
    for j in dict[i]: #This iterates through the inner lists
        if j is None:
            temp.append('None')
        else:
            temp.append(j)
        temp2 = {str(i):temp}
        new_dict.update(temp2)

    print(new_dict)
```

*We will navigate from inner to outer*

1. Convert your explicit `if` statement to a ternary form

   ```
   new_dict = {}
   for i in ur_dict: #This accesses each dictionary key.
       temp = []
       for j in ur_dict[i]: #This iterates through the inner lists
           temp.append('None' if j is None else j)
           temp2 = {str(i):temp}
       new_dict.update(temp2)
   ```
2. Convert the Inner Loop to list comprehension

   ```
   new_dict = {}
   for i in ur_dict: #This accesses each dictionary key.
       temp = ['None' if elem is None else elem 
               for elem in ur_dict[i]]
       temp2 = {str(i): temp}
       new_dict.update(temp2)
   ```
3. Convert the Outer Loop to dict comprehension

   ```
   {key : ['None' if elem is None else elem 
           for elem in value] 
    for key, value in ur_dict.items()}
   ```

**Note**, if you are using `python 2.X`, instead of `ur_dict.items()` use `ur_dict.iteritems()`

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks for the detailed explanation. I agree, it seems list/dict comprehension is not particularly intuitive or natural to newbies. Do you mind recommending a resource or two for deep dive into comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with modifying the original dictionary in place, you could also do

```
for lst in my_dict.values():
    lst[:] = map(str, lst)
```

This will simply stringify all list items in place, regardless of whether they are `None` or not.